# terminal emulator on WSL2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I installed xterm on WSL2 on my machine.
However, I cannot copy text from outside into the xterm window... (I can copy and paste between xterm windows).

Afterwards, I installed terminator

```
sudo apt-get install terminator
```

The window appears but I get the error:

```
ConfigBase::load: Unable to open /home/pc/.config/terminator/config ([Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pc/.config/terminator/config')
Gdk-Message: 15:53:32.137: Unable to load hand2 from the cursor theme
<window.Window object at 0x7f9f84073b80 (terminatorlib+window+Window at 0x2116500)> is not in registered window list
```

Does anyone know of how to copy external text into xterm or a suitable alternative o xterm for WSL?

Best regards

Comment: There is always bash.

Comment: How can you lunch a new terminal? I am creating "windows" with xterm for running gdb

Comment: I don't understand this.  You are already in a terminal when you typed `sudo apt-get install terminator`.  xterm is x11 and for this specific task, pointless.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, yes. I want to debug code in parallel and for that I need new windows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329259/how-do-i-debug-an-mpi-program.  However, if I want to copy and paste from outside of xterm I cannot do it. But it works in terminator, so the approach would be to replace terminator with xterm, but I get the errors/warnigs in the post

Comment: Good to see you have it resolved, but I see in another question that you have other xterm issues.  Have you considered Windows Terminal as an alternative?  It supports multiple WSL tabs, copy/paste between Windows and WSL, is open-source, actively developed by Microsoft, available for installation through the Microsoft Store, and is just far beyond xterm in feature set (and pretty much any Linux terminal, IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by:

```
touch ~.Xdefaults
```

And pasting inside:

```
XTerm*VT100.Translations:       #override\n\
 Shift Ctrl <KeyPress> v: insert-selection(CLIPBOARD)\n\
 Shift Ctrl <KeyPress> c: copy-selection(CLIPBOARD)\n
```